# Anypoint Studio : Warning - There were problems disposing the mule classloader

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

**Issue:**

I am using Anypoint Studio Version: 6.6.5 Build Id: 202005271503, working on Mule 3.8.4.
I work on Mavenized projects, and always see this warning message in Error console "There were problems disposing the mule classloader".

Read multiple blogs in stackoverflow and help.mulesoft, but none of the blogs explain how to actually fix this warning in Anypoint Studio.
This doesn't cause any application issues but would like to really understand what's causing this issue.

Exception stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$6 from class org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getSystemProperty(LogFactory.java:1442)
```

**Solution Updated**

Adding below dependency in project POM resolved the issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding below dependency in project POM resolved the issue.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a classloading problem related to the DataWeave editor. Try a fresh install of 6.6.5 and use a fresh workspace.

Comment: Thanks Aled. Tried this already, have multiple workspaces. Throws same warning in all workspaces.

Comment: have you tried to install from a fresh download too?

Comment: Yes i have tried this too. At some point of time, i can start seeing this warning message. Am i missing some configuration?

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue was solved after installing java 8 and correcting the path variable to point to the same.
You can check this link to set the Java version: https://www.happycoders.eu/java/how-to-switch-multiple-java-versions-windows/